# When using RedirectToAction it is not preserving my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

When I am catching a HttpPost, I am redirecting to another ResultAction. It is preserving my int values, but not my list values. Can't seem to figure out why. If I get the post with page number = 2, searchAction = 3 and clearanceResults (a List) with 25 items. It comes back with what I would expect on the post, however when I get to the Details ActionResult, it only preserves pageNumber and searchAction, not the list of clearanceResults. Weird thing, the list isn't null, it just has a count of 0.

Model:

```
public class ClearanceListViewModel
{
    public ClearanceListViewModel()
    {
        this.pageNumber = 1;
        this.searchAction = 1;
        this.lastPage = false;
    }

    public ClearanceListViewModel(int pageNumber, int searchAction)
    {
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
        this.searchAction = searchAction;            
    }

    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public int searchAction { get; set; }
    public List<ClearanceViewModel> clearanceResults { get; set; }
    public bool lastPage { get; set; }
}
```

Post in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(ClearanceListViewModel model, FormCollection collection)
    {
        ClearanceListViewModel cModel = new ClearanceListViewModel();
        cModel = model;
        cModel.clearanceResults = model.clearanceResults;
        // do something
        return RedirectToAction("Details", cModel);
    }
```

Action Result in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(ClearanceListViewModel model)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<ClearanceViewModel> clearanceList = new List<ClearanceViewModel>();

        //save any changes
        if (model.clearanceResults != null)
        {
            ClearanceSave(model);
            model.clearanceResults = null;
        }

        string inQuery = "select sku, qty from products";

        // call the query
        dt = AS400DAL.Instance.ExecuteQueryAsDataTable(inQuery);

        model = Utility.Utility.ProcessClearanceSkus(dt, model);
        return View("Index",model);
    }
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study the overloads of [`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). None of the allow the passing of a model. Normally your post would modify the database, and then you'd redirect to an action that recreates the model from the database. Because redirection is something that occurs at the client, the redirected request is entirely separate from the post that issued the redirect, so the model is not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a session to store the model,

You can do:

```
Session["mymodel"] = model;
```

Then after your redirect get the model from the session by doing

```
ClearanceListViewModel newModel = (ClearanceListViewModel)Session["mymodel"];
```

This will allow you to pass the model successfully

Comment: All good until you publish on a webfarm, then the wheels fall off.

Comment: @spender are they publishing to a web farm?

Comment: If not, then it's no problem, but I do believe that persisting state in the webserver has a bad smell to it.

Comment: No we are not. I did this for something else, but I just moved the save into the post and it worked.